# Where to return to after an unsuccessful payment to PayPal

Tags: html, paypal

I am setting up a PayPal BuyNow button on my static site. I have been into the PayPal business area and specified the URL of the auto-return for a successful payment. Where do I specify the URL to return to when an UNSUCCESSFUL attempt is made at making a payment?

Comment: According to the documentation the response from PayPal will indicate success or failure. Therefore, you should be checking this status in the url endpoint you’ve specified as the auto-return.

Comment: Thanks for that Sid.  Now I just have to find out how to check the status.  (I've been using Dreamweaver to design the pages and am not really familiar with html.)

Comment: What language are you using to handle the request/response?

Comment: Hi Sid  Thanks again for your response.  The sad fact is I don't really know. I manage several web sites but they are all simple and have all been designed using Dream Weaver in its WYSIWYG form.  I looked up how to add a PayPal link on the page and I've done that.  (Code below) and I've specified the URL to which I wish to return after the purchase has been made but I don't know how to interrogate the return process.  Can you point me at a reference guide that I could look at?  Here is a small piece of the code.  You'll be able to see which language it uses.

Comment: src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</td>
    <td width="5%" valign="top" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="Text1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFF99">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="74%" colspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="Text1">(C) Worsfold Software Ltd 2018</td>
  </tr>

Comment: ... and I've now purchased "PayPal for Dummies" for my Kindle, so I've got some reading to do.